# I need help solving this Lagrange Multiplier Problem.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

This is Solution provided, but I do know they came up with $\mu$ and the values for $x$, $y$, and $z$. Any help would be appreciated. Please solve using Lagrange multipliers with the two given constraints.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgbuv.png)

Comment: Plug the value of $\lambda$ into the second and third equations to find $y(\mu)$ and $z(\mu)$, then plug those into the last equation to get a relation for $\mu$; for any particular solution to that equation you have a pair $(y,z)$ corresponding to that value of $\mu$. Then use the fourth equation to find $x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on the solution: we have $f(x,y,z) = x+2y$, $g(x,y,z) = x+y+z$, and $h(x,y,z) = y^2+z^2$. Calculating gradients, we get $\nabla f = (1,2,0)$, $\nabla g = (1,1,1)$, and $\nabla h = (0,2y,2z)$. We arrive at the system of equations:
$$ \nabla f = \lambda \nabla g+\mu\nabla h$$
Substituting in gradients:
$$ (1,2,0)=\lambda(1,1,1)+\mu(0,2y,2z)$$
Arriving at the system of equations mentioned:
$$  1=\lambda \\
 2 = \lambda + 2\mu y \\
0 = \lambda +2\mu z\\
1 = x+y+z\\
4 = y^2+z^2$$
Plugging $\lambda = 1$ into the second equation yields $1=2\mu y$. Similarly, for the third equation, we get $-1=2\mu z$, from which we see that $-y=z$ and thus $y^2=(-y)^2=z^2$. Using that for the last equality, we have: $2y^2 = 4$ and so $y = \pm \sqrt{2} = -z$. Revisiting the fourth equality, we have that $x=1$ since $y=-z \iff y+z=0$. Finally we can arrive at the optimum: $(1,\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$ and $(1,-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$. Hopefully that clears up how they arrived at their values for $x,y,z$!

Comment: Thank you very much